# How it possible that you can use setters in constant classes?

Tags: dart

I was testing something in Flutter and created this class but when i made a setter i got no errors .

```
class ConstClass {
  final int? x;
  // constructor here has no body
  const ConstClass(this.x);
  
  int? get X => x;
  
  set x(int? val) => x = val;
}
```

so why setters are allowed in Const Classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a member variable `x` that is [*shadowed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) by the `x` setter.  Consequently static analysis does not recognize that `x` is `final` (because there is a setter *also* named `x`), so there is no error about trying to re-assign a `final` variable.  If you fix the name collision, you will get an appropriate error:

```dart
class ConstClass {
  final int? _x;

  const ConstClass(this._x);
  
  int? get x => _x;
  
  // Error: '_x' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
  set x(int? val) => _x = val; 
}
```

If you're asking why a setter is allowed to exist at all on a class with a `const` constructor, remember that a setter is just a function call.  It can do arbitrary things and doesn't necessarily need to mutate `this`:

```dart
class Printer {
  const Printer();

  set outputValue(Object? o) => print(o);
}

void main() {
  (const Printer()).outputValue = "Hello world!";
}
```

Is that a good design for an API?  No, not really (at least for that particular example), but it's something that you *can* do.